# Snap (editing tools) in ArcGIS not working properly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, snapping

I am using the snap tool to match one polygon file to another, using the EDGE Snapping Environment Type Option. The tool appears to work properly for the vertices of the input feature polygons that are outside of the snap environment polygon, but vertices of the input feature that are within the snap environment feature will not snap to it.

Is this the way the tool is supposed to work, or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide more precise details of what you did, please?  I think a picture would help.